Parse, transpose and insert a new row
I have a large spreadsheet and need to parse, transpose and insert the parsed values into a new row.
My sample data:

What I need to do is format the sheet to read as below:

I tried
TOCOL(A2:(transpose(SPLIT(B2,",")))) 

but that doesn't work. TIA.

Similar Question 1, Similar 2

Make sure to provide input and expected output as plain text table in the question. Check my answer or other options to create a table easily, which are easy to copy/paste.  Avoid sharing links like spreadsheets, which make the question useless for others or images, which are hard to copy. Also, note that your email address can also be accessed by the public, if you share Google files.

Thanks for those links ...here's what worked for me =ARRAYFORMULA(TRIM(QUERY(SPLIT(FLATTEN(IF(IFERROR(SPLIT(B2:B, ","))="",,
A2:A&"×"&SPLIT(B2:B, ","))), "×"),
"where Col2 is not null")))
